# Codeigniter 4 and SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, codeigniter-4

after leaving programming about 10 years ago, i am trying to use Codeigniter 4.
My problem is getting an array from an XML file.
So I was thinking of using PHP's SimpleXMLElement but I can't access this class because it is being searched in the wrong path.
Here is an example of my code:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Helloworld extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {

        $xmlstr = '<libri>
        <libro> 
            <autore>J.K.Rowlings</autore> 
            <titolo>Harry Potter e la pietra filosofale</titolo> 
            <editore>Salani</editore> 
        </libro>
        <libro> 
            <autore>J.R.Tolkien</autore> 
            <titolo>Il signore degli Anelli</titolo> 
            <editore>Bonpiani</editore> 
        </libro> 
        </libri>';

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

    }
}
```

And this is the error i get:

**Class 'App\Controllers\SimpleXMLElement' not found**

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this

```
new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
```

Add a backslash befor `SimpleXMLElement`

Comment: you're welcome, if my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you choose it as the best answer as you wish.